# What is the package name of the default overlay audio/music/MP3 player of Android 9?

Tags: samsung, audio, uninstallation, music-player, mp3-player

I have accidentally disabled it on my Samsung A40 by doing `pm uninstall --user 0` in the `adb` shell and would like to reinstall it, but cannot remember the package name. The player is very minimalist, featuring only a rudimentary overlay bar with play/pause/stop buttons, and does not have any other functions or settings (such as equalizer, playlist etc.).

When trying to open e.g. an MP3 file, I get the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

I already did `diff <(adb shell pm list packages) <(adb shell pm list packages -u)` and went through the complete list of uninstalled packages, but there is none that has *"music"*, *"audio"*, or *"player"* in its name, and it is also none of the ones with *"sound"* (e.g. `com.sec.android.app.soundalive`). Also, I never had `com.google.android.music` and `com.samsung.music` to begin with, which are this vendor's default players.

This package must either have some obscure name or a disabled system package is causing a problem indirectly.